# Test driven development for C++ XPCOM component?

Tags: c++, tdd, xpcom

I want to create a Firefox extension using c++ XPCOM component which in turn uses javascript XPCOM component. Is there any framework that allows test driven development of C++ XPCOM component/firefox extension ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could copy what Mozilla [uses to test native code](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/xpcom/tests/TestHarness.h).  You just have to make sure you link with libxul (which may require that you build Firefox).

An example file that uses TestHarness.h [can be found here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/storage/test/test_statement_scoper.cpp).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to sdwilsh's suggestion, you could use another test framework mozilla uses - [xpcshell tests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Writing_xpcshell-based_unit_tests). This is also the easiest to setup if you build Firefox.